# How to perform a sumif using blank cells as a reference?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Please see the example data below:

```
Time        Date                Result
00:21.6     10/1/2012 1:43      FALSE
01:47.7     10/1/2012 2:13      FALSE
00:56.7     10/1/2012 2:49      FALSE
00:54.9     10/1/2012 3:43  
00:11.8     10/1/2012 3:43  
02:10.9     10/1/2012 3:46      FALSE
01:05.4     10/1/2012 3:58      FALSE
00:55.8     10/1/2012 4:53  
04:41.8     10/1/2012 4:52  
00:26.3     10/1/2012 4:58  
00:04.2     10/1/2012 4:58  
00:15.3     10/1/2012 4:59  
00:06.4     10/1/2012 4:57  
00:10.7     10/1/2012 4:56  
00:04.4     10/1/2012 4:56  
00:04.2     10/1/2012 4:57  
00:29.2     10/1/2012 4:57  
00:34.5     10/1/2012 4:56  
01:22.4     10/1/2012 4:55  
00:08.1     10/1/2012 4:55      FALSE
03:20.9     10/1/2012 4:51      FALSE
00:56.3     10/1/2012 5:42      FALSE
02:23.1     10/1/2012 5:51      
01:20.6     10/1/2012 5:48  
00:09.8     10/1/2012 5:49      FALSE
01:40.0     10/1/2012 7:47      FALSE
01:13.4     10/1/2012 8:11      FALSE
00:41.6     10/1/2012 9:49      FALSE
01:08.1     10/1/2012 11:56     FALSE
```

I need to perform a certain type of calculation. If there is no blank cell in the result, I need the data in time cell next to the result. But if there is a blank cell in the result column, I need to perform a sum of the time in the rows that contain the blank cell and the first cell containing FALSE next to the blank cell.

Please see the example output below:

```
00:21.6     10/1/2012 1:43      FALSE       00:21.6
01:47.7     10/1/2012 2:13      FALSE       01:47.7
00:56.7     10/1/2012 2:49      FALSE       00:56.7
00:54.9     10/1/2012 3:43      
00:11.8     10/1/2012 3:43      
02:10.9     10/1/2012 3:46      FALSE       03:17.6(i.e., 00:54.9+00:11.8+02:10.9)
01:05.4     10/1/2012 3:58      FALSE       01:05.4
00:55.8     10/1/2012 4:53      
04:41.8     10/1/2012 4:52      
00:26.3     10/1/2012 4:58      
00:04.2     10/1/2012 4:58      
00:15.3     10/1/2012 4:59      
00:06.4     10/1/2012 4:57      
00:10.7     10/1/2012 4:56      
00:04.4     10/1/2012 4:56      
00:04.2     10/1/2012 4:57      
00:29.2     10/1/2012 4:57      
00:34.5     10/1/2012 4:56      
01:22.4     10/1/2012 4:55      
00:08.1     10/1/2012 4:55      FALSE       09:23.3(i.e., 00:55.8+04:41.8+00:26.3+00:04.2+00:15.3+00:06.4+00:10.7+00:04.4+00:04.2+00:29.2+00:34.5+01:22.4+00:08.1)
03:20.9     10/1/2012 4:51      FALSE       03:20.9
00:56.3     10/1/2012 5:42      FALSE       00:56.3
02:23.1     10/1/2012 5:51      
01:20.6     10/1/2012 5:48      
00:09.8     10/1/2012 5:49      FALSE       03:53.5(i.e., 02:23.1+01:20.6+00:09.8)
01:40.0     10/1/2012 7:47      FALSE       01:40.0
01:13.4     10/1/2012 8:11      FALSE       01:13.4
00:41.6     10/1/2012 9:49      FALSE       00:41.6
01:08.1     10/1/2012 11:56     FALSE       01:08.1
```

If it is possible by any formulas or using visual basic editor please let me know. I am doing this manually right now. I have to handle about 10000-15000 rows per day. If you help me out I could save a lot of hours and use it to learn something new.

Comment: I don't think using formulas alone would be possible or at least it would be way more work than by using VBA if you know this already. This is only a matter of having a variable hold the running total and reset it each time you encounter `FALSE`.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur +1, and yet for some reason I can't stop trying to figure it out with a single formula :)

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur Thanks for the insight. Can you suggest me anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this if you prefer using VBA:

```
Sub SmartRunningTotals()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim totalTime As Double

    ' I'm assuming your time column is in column A
    lastRow = Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = Range("A2:A" & lastRow)

    For Each cell In rng
        totalTime = totalTime + cell.Value
        If cell.Offset(, 2).Value <> "" Then
            cell.Offset(, 3).Value = totalTime
            ' reset total after we write it to column D
            totalTime = 0
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Can you change this code, so that the Time is in column H, date is in I, and Result is in M? I need the total to be in Column N. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @Dinesh, just change the `"A"` to `"H"` in the code for your time column, then modify the number in the `cell.offset` to reference the columns you want to use. For example, `cell.offset(,5)` means 5 columns to the right of your Time column. And please accept my answer by clicking the check box.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty easy in two columns. Calculate a running total and reset if the cell above is not blank.

E.g.

> (Time = Column H,   Date = Column I,  Result = Column J )

```
Column N
    =IF(J1="",H2+N1,H2)
    =IF(J2="",H3+N2,H3)
    =IF(J3="",H4+N3,H4)
    =IF(J4="",H5+N4,H5)
    =IF(J5="",H6+N5,H6)

Column O

    =IF(J2="","",O2)
    =IF(J3="","",O3)
    =IF(J4="","",O4)
    =IF(J5="","",O5)
    =IF(J6="","",O6)
```

Copy those formulas on down

Comment: Changed the column names to fit what you describe

Answer (score 1):

Assuming data starts at row 2 with headers in row 1 then you can use this formula in D2 copied down

`=IF(C2<>"",SUM(A$2:A2)-SUM(D$1:D1),"")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your existing range starts in cell A1 (i.e. the word `"Time"` exists in cell A1).  I am also assuming that in column C, the two possible values are the logical value `FALSE` (not the text string `"FALSE"`), or blank (not a string of 1 or more spaces).

In cell D1, enter the formula `=IF(AND(C2=FALSE,C1=""),D1+1,1)`

In cell E1, enter the formula `=IF(C2="","",SUM(OFFSET(A2,-(D2-1),0,D2,1)))`

Set the number format in cell E1 to `"mm:ss.0"`

Copy D1 and E1 all the way down your range.  Hide column D if desired.

Comment: It seems that this answer doesn't work for me. Head of Catering's code works fine. I need some modifications to be done in it.